# Known techniques to identify a user

Tags: security, identity

Some say that flash cookies is one of them that's not that popular.

The most used is the ip(I heard sometimes it's combined with the user-agent)

Assuming the ip is dynamic, what are the known techniques to identify a user that's accessing your website?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

I don't want any library or anything. I wanna know what those libraries use to do their job.

And that's based just on the user first request to the website. So if the user access it again, how can I know if it's the same user or not?

Comment: Ive heard Modernizr is pretty good, but never used it personally. http://modernizr.com/

Comment: Thanks @cgatian but I think I wasn't clear enough. Edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming based on your question that having users register and log in is not an option for you?

Typically using the IP address is a reliable way to determine approximate location (though not always), but *not* identity.  User agent is even less reliable, especially nowadays when browser extensions are actively switching user's user agents without them even knowing.

Cookies work well if the user accepts them.  If using cookies, generate a random ID string and set it.  Have them submit it at each request.  If you get a request with no cookie, issue a new one.

Flash can also work well for "unmasking" individuals that are hiding over Tor or other proxy services, however many users disable flash as well.

Check out [this page for a discussion of unmasking users with Flash or Java](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=78041.0).  Also, [this question has some interesting info on finding users behind proxies](https://superuser.com/questions/284927/how-to-get-the-real-ip-address-of-someone-using-a-proxy).

The best you will be able to get is an approximation, not an outright identity.

Comment: So, basically, ip is the only way to identify the user? And that's possible even with proxy? wow

Comment: @PatrickBassut IP is also totally unreliable for anything other than a best guess.  Mobile users regularly change IPs and many IPs are shared between multiple users.

Comment: So, at the end of the day: there's no reliable way to identify a user, right?

Comment: @PatrickBassut yes, if users don't accept cookies and they don't have login accounts, there's no way to individually identify a user.  Even if they do accept cookies there's still a chance they could tamper with it or clear cookies during a session and receive a new "ID"